# Hilt injection is null

Tags: null, code-injection, dagger, dagger-hilt

I try to use HIlt injection but the injectet object is null

have all dependencies:

app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'

dependencies {
 implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44'
 annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.44'
 kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.44'
 implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0'
}
```

build/gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.7.0.300'
    classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.46.1'
}
```

```
@HiltAndroidApp
public class AppApplication extends Application {

///
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
object AppHiltModule {
    @Provides
    fun prefs(@ApplicationContext appContext: Context): Prefs {
        return Prefs(appContext, appConf(appContext))
    }

///
@AndroidEntryPoint
abstract public class AppStateFragmentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Inject
    protected Prefs prefs;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
      setTheme(prefs.getTheme()); // null
    }
}
```

but setTheme(prefs.getTheme()); prefs is null

Do I need to set some additional settings or something like in the dagger:
`AppApplication.getComponent(this).inject(this); //the old dagger implementation`

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
   super.onCreate(bundle);
   //and then
   setTheme(prefs.getTheme());
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**